# add_action in namespace not working

Tags: php, oop, namespace

I decided to namespace my plugin, and I got it all to work, except in my main plugin file.

I added two actions in that plugin, before calling the init method of the plugin.

```
<?php
namespace myPlugin;

add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_activation_notice' );

function add_activation_notice() {
    add_action( 'admin_notices', 'activation_notice' );
}

function activation_notice() {
    echo 'Notice!';
}
```

But this throws error

> **Uncaught Error**: Undefined constant 'myPlugin\myPlugin\add_activation_notice'

I'm rather new to namespacing, so I don't know why this happens.

The two functions `add_activation_notice` and `activation_notice` are in the `myPlugin` namespace. Most of the code I found online reference methods inside classes, but I need these to be outside of a class so that I can have plugin activation notice.

EDIT:

When I try with

```
add_action( 'admin_init', \add_activation_notice() );
```

I get

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add_activation_notice()

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Before going too far down this path I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with [PHP name resolution rules](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php).

To answer your actual question -

When you namespace functions, the fully qualified name of those functions includes the namespace.

In your example, you have defined two functions: `\myPlugin\add_activation_notice` and `\myPlugin\activation_notice`.

When calling either of these from within the `myPlugin` namespace, you can use the unqualified name (i.e. `activation_notice()`) but outside of the `myPlugin` namespace you have to follow the name resolution rules linked above.

In the case of `add_action()` - while this is called from within your `myPlugin` namespace, you are not passing the actual function but rather the function name as a string. WordPress later attempts to call that function from the global namespace.

The solution to your problem should be to include the `myPlugin` namespace in the function name passed to `add_action` (pay special attention to the escaped backslash):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'myPlugin\\add_activation_notice' );
add_action( 'admin_notice', 'myPlugin\\activation_notice' );
```

My preferred method of doing this would be by concatenating the [`__NAMESPACE__` magic constant](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) which simplifies things slightly if you should you ever decide to change your namespaces:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\add_activation_notice' );
add_action( 'admin_notice', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\activation_notice' );
```

Comment: In my updated answer I've used your suggested `__NAMESPACE__` method.

Comment: I'll try this, I didn't try with escaped backshlash. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to enclose your code in curly brackets:

```
namespace myPlugin {

    add_action( 'admin_init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\add_activation_notice' );

    function add_activation_notice() {
        add_action( 'admin_notice', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\activation_notice' );
    }

    function activation_notice() {
        echo 'Notice!';
    }
}
```

Otherwise, your action will look for `activation_notice` function in a global namespace.

### Update

There is no `admin_notice` hook. Use `admin_notices` instead. Try:

```
namespace myPlugin {
    add_action( 'admin_init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\add_activation_notice');

    function add_activation_notice() {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\activation_notice' );
    }

    function activation_notice() {
    ?>
        <div class="notice notice-info is-dismissible">
            <p><?php echo 'Done!'; ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: With this I get: `
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'add_activation_notice' not found or invalid function name`

Comment: Read my updated answer.

Comment: `admin_notice` was probably a typo :D I had the code without namespacing and it worked, so it's 99% a typo :)