# How do I add an action using namespaces, and file separation?

Tags: plugins, actions, namespace

I'm working on a plugin, and I'm trying to get to grips with namespaces and how they work with actions. In a separate file, I have a single function with a namespace declared at the top:

```
namespace verism\ImageUpload;

function image_upload() {
    ...
    echo 'function successfully called';
    wp_die();
}
```

In the main plugin php file I'm trying to add an action as follows:

```
namespace verism;

use function verism\ImageUpload\image_upload as image_upload;

add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_image_from_url', 'image_upload' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_set_image_from_url', 'image_upload' );
```

I have also tried:

```
namespace verism;

use function verism\ImageUpload\image_upload as image_upload;

add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_image_from_url', '\verism\ImageUpload\image_upload' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_set_image_from_url', '\verism\ImageUpload\image_upload' );
```

However, none of these approaches work - when I log the AJAX result to the console, I always get "0".

**Note:** If I copy the `image_upload` function into the main file, I can see the correct result, the issue seems to only be when it's located in a separate file.

Can anyone shed some light?

**EDIT:** This question was deemed too similar to [an existing one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284877/add-action-in-namespace-not-working), and so has been closed, so I cannot accept an answer. However, this question deals with a different issue, namely that of requiring—rather than using—a separate file. User Rup was kind enough to offer the correct answer to the problem, in the comments.

Comment: AJAX handlers don't get given parameters so you can't use `($url, $post_id = 0)`, otherwise `add_action` is expecting a `callable` type value, which is a standard PHP type, so the official PHP docs will have the answer you seek

Comment: Where you add them doesn't matter. You need the full name, i.e. `add_action('..', '\verism\ImageUpload\image_upload');`.

Comment: The last version looks OK to me. Is that other file definitely included / required?

Comment: The `namespace` and `use function` lines won't matter because the hook handler code doesn't have that context: it's only got the string you're giving it to look up the function to call.

Comment: I think you can also give it the function as a function rather than a name, i.e. `add_action( 'wp_ajax_set_image_from_url', image_upload );`. In this case the namespace and use functions are used.

Comment: @Rup PHP definitely didn't like me trying a non-string... Also, to make sure I'm not missing anything, I was under the impression I only needed to `use` the file, or should I try including it somehow instead/as well?

Comment: I don't think you can just do that with use, no (but I might be wrong!). I'd try `require_once 'image_upload.php';`, or whatever the relative path to the new file is. (Or it's possible composer will generate all the includes/requires for you if you're using that, but I don't really know composer.)

Comment: BINGO! That seems to have solved it. If you want to add it as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Glad you've solved it! I can't add an answer because the question is closed.