# Custom AJAX Endpoint not returning any result

Tags: ajax, database

Hello I'm new to Wordpress and I'm trying to create an ajax endpoint that outputs JSON so I can access it through jQuery Datatables. I'm using Air Light theme for my current site and what happens when I go into `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ajax_endpoint` is that it just gives me 0. I tried querying posts, users, and my custom tables they all give me 0 even though I have a status code 200.

I'm wondering if there's something wrong I'm doing here. I've also tried putting an echo somewhere in the function and it does not show up.

*functions.php*

```
namespace Air_Light;

/**
 * The current version of the theme.
 */
define( 'AIR_LIGHT_VERSION', '8.3.2' );

/**
 * Theme setup code
*/


add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_endpoint', 'ajax_endpoint');
add_action('wp_ajax_no_priv_ajax_endpoint', 'ajax_endpoint');
function ajax_endpoint(){
  global $wpdb;
  $results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM table');
  
  echo json_encode($results);
  wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the defined namespace as the prefix for the `add_action` callbacks so that PHP knows which function it is supposed to call. More on this here, [add_action in namespace not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284877/add-action-in-namespace-not-working)

The `add_action`s should look like this then,

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_endpoint', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\ajax_endpoint');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_endpoint', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\ajax_endpoint');
```

When doing development work it is a good idea to have debugging on so that you can check `debug.log` for error messages, which usually tell you what is wrong with the code and why it isn't working. [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)

As a side note, for sending a json response you can also use [wp_send_json()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/), [wp_send_json_error()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_error/), and [wp_send_json_success()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is because of incorrect hook_name. You have used `wp_ajax_no_priv_{$action}` instead of `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}`

Also use `wp_send_json()` for send response in json format.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_endpoint', 'ajax_endpoint');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_endpoint', 'ajax_endpoint');
function ajax_endpoint(){
  $results = array("Test Result");
  wp_send_json($results);
  wp_die();
}
```